# Change body background color on link hover

Tags: html, css

How can I change the the page background when the mouse is hovered on a `a`? I'm looking for a css only solution.

I know that you can reach the child elements via css but I have no idea how/if you can reach the body.

Comment: You cannot do that using a pure css solution as far as I know

Comment: @Mia you can do that using `jquery` though.

Comment: You must understand first the basic,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Mike Ross' demo solves your problem, it doesn't explain how or why it works. It can also be dramatically simplified.

Basically you want to use the [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) notation on your element. This creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the associated element, for which you can apply extra styling. You can then style the `::before` selector to fill the screen with a particular background colour. For example:

```
<a class="special">Test</a>

.special:hover:before{
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

You don't need `nth-of-type` in there or anything else. See my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/exqrjfmo/). All you need to do is make sure that the before element is full screen, in the back of the z order and has a particular color.

Comment: very nice - what if I want to display different colors for each item? colors are in a custom data-color attribute

Comment: Just separate the colours into extra classes. For example, `.special-blue:hover:before` which just contains `background-color: #00ff00`. Then your link would have the classes `special special-blue`.

Comment: I have dynamically generated objects on my page --- the divs are created by the server, with a data-color attribute (of course this can be anything else during creation) but this looks like I will have to create a hover for every color possibility upfront.... which is hard.

Comment: @mattWay you are right, i just got the idea from the link i shared and another answer on stackoverflow. Anyway yours is very simple and to the point, i am trying to update my code

Comment: Even though this does not fully solve my problem, this is the closest anwer. I'm marking this as the solutiın. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/bjsvhze8/)

Here is `html` part of it

```
<a href="">link 1</a>
```

And here is the `css`

```
body {
        background: lightblue;
    }
    a:hover:before {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: grey;
    }
```

Comment: I will just add to the demo that `a:hover:before` should be `position: fixed;` because maybe the link is in container with `position: relative;` and then the background will appear according to the containers position.

Comment: Are you able to bring the key parts of the code into this answer so we have it for reference on SO? The link might rot and your answer will no longer be useful...