# Change background colour on hover over button

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to create a button which, when hovered over, changes the background colour of my website.

I have no idea how to attempt this and am looking for any help people can give.

You can see the effect I am trying to replicate on the desktop version of the [nowthisnews.com](http://nowthisnews.com) website when you hover over the social icons.

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You have to at least attempt to accomplish this yourself.

Comment: Right here, duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337295/change-body-background-color-on-link-hover

Comment: One can learn a lot when using a web inspector to look at the code of a particular website and see what it does. Most browsers have that function built in, personally I like the one from Google Chrome. If you look at the _script.js_ file on that URL you sent, you'll quickly discover how this is being done.

Comment: Hi Guys, why you are posting answers here, why not you guys giving to  the instructions to solve his issue by his own. So that he can learn the thing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```js
function bgChange(x) {
    document.body.style.background = x;
}
```

```css
   

ul li{
  color:#fff;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:2px;
  margin:7px;
}
ul li a{
color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="" onmouseover="bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)" style="background:red;">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onmouseover="bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)" style="background:green;">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onmouseover="bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)" style="background:blue;">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onmouseover="bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)"
           style="background:yellow;">yellow</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Hi. This is perfect but the image I am using to hover over also has the same background colour. Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.column-1').mouseover(function() {
    $('.mask-1').css("background-color", "#061981");
     ......

 });
}
```

essentially a mouseover(function  ... on the area you want observ .. perform a changing on css  backgrond-color related the proper div (in this case the div class mask-1)

you can easly inspect the code using firebugs on inspecting code provided by the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jquery to style the background css. just make sure the jquery file is included on the page and modify the code below with your element id's

```
$('#button-name').hover(function(){
     $('#background-name').css('background-color':'red'); 
});
```